# What is the origin of the naming convention for position functions?

Tags: terminology, conventions, notation, distance, displacement

In physics, position as a function of time is generally called $d(t)$ or $s(t)$. Using "$d$" is pretty intuitive, however I haven't been able to figure out why "$s$" is used as well. Is it possibly based on another language?

Comment: it could be based on the german word 'Strecke', but I don't think this convention is that strict in the first place.

Comment: Yes, $s$ stands for the german word _Strecke,_ and $d$ for _distance._

Comment: I prefer r(t) for position (i.e., instantaneous displacement from the reference point), to distinguish it from displacement (change in position over a time interval) s(t) and from distance travelled d(t).

Comment: Do we know what is origin of usage of 's' as a "Strecke", i.e. who started using it or when? 100 years ago? 200-300 years ago? 500 years ago? 2000 years ago? Etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As commenters have pointed out, it's German *Strecke*.

Note that $s$ is for *displacement*, whereas $d$ is for *distance*. Distance is the distance along the path traveled by a body, whereas displacement is the birds-eye distance traveled. Displacement can also be negative in 1-D, depending upon your reference positive direction.

For some reason, even though *Strecke* actually means *distance*, not *displacement*, its symbol is used for *displacement*.

You might want to check out [this paper](http://www.wpi.edu/Pubs/E-project/Available/E-project-030509-114708/unrestricted/symbols.pdf), it's got an analysis of the naming, mainly for electrodynamic units. A few symbols from the table at the end of the paper: $c$ (speed of light) comes from Latin *celeritas*; $I$ (current) comes from "intensity of current" in French (*intensite du courant*). The $\mathbf{A}$-potential, $\mathbf{B}$-field, $\mathbf{H}$-field got their symbols from the alphabetic order of the others.

Comment: Community wiki as I'm just answer-ifying the comments.

Comment: Comment to the answer(v1): Note that _Strecke_ and  _distance_ usually denote non-negative quantities, while a _displacement_ is a relative change in _position,_ and therefore can be both positive and negative.

Comment: I've added it, though you could have added it yourself. It's community wiki for that reason; I myself don't know much about it.

Comment: I thought it might have been a misreading of a lower case delta.